# Views/widgets under ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

My problem is this;

I have an expandableListView with just 1 group(to use expand effect of child views) on top my layout and there are some views/widgets under it(not mentioning child ones). By using layout_weight, all widgets use screen height %100. When it is expanded, some views are pushed under the bottom of the screen which is fine **as long as** i can scroll through them but i can't. Because i cannot use scroll view with expandablelist view so they(ones under the screen) can not be reached/viewed while group is expanded.

Other than using expandablelist view, how can i reach that expand effect from a other widget or custom my code?

My Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/mainLL">



<ExpandableListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_marginTop = "10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    

     android:id="@+id/expandableStudentList"> 

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Lorem ipsum duromet"/>

    <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:text="Save"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/save2"/>

</ExpandableListView>// Not supported this way I must move two widgets to       outside

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try adding `TextView` and `Button` as ExpandableListView's footer? (actually last item in a list)

Comment: Check post again pls? Like this? I didnt know it can be done? So they could be seen by scrolling this way? In code i have to reach them by expandablelistview.findViewById right? No didn't work, it said it is not supported.

Comment: @ Mert Serimer Move `TextView` and `Button` into another xml, lets call it view_expandablelist_footer.xml. Then, in you adapter under `public View getGroupView(int pos, boolean isExpanded, View v, ViewGroup p)` put `if (pos == myList.size()) { LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater(); v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_expandablelist_footer, p, false); holder.txtLoremIpsum = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_lorem_ipsum); ... `

Comment: Thank you and i understand your point. But what you say is functional and doable in simple cases such as this. What if i have nested linearlayouts and lots of textviews and buttons etc =))

Comment: @ Mert Serimer Every view is reachable via `v.findViewById`. I can't think of another solution for scrolling.

Comment: Thank you anyway. In seperate layouts, weight calculations size calculations and fitting them correctly is harder. I will change my style=)